# JAVA - How to work out last day of a month entered by the user

Tags: java

If the user enters a numerical value 1-12 for a month, how can I change my code below so that it outputs the maximum number of days for that month entered by user.

```
import java.util.*;

public class LastDay {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);       
    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();

    int myMonth;

    System.out.println("Enter the month number (1-12): ");
    myMonth = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Maximum number of days is: " + Calendar.getInstance().getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));     
}
```

}

At the moment it outputs the max number of days for month we're currently in (March). I would like for it to do it for myMonth value entered by user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the month before:

```
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, myMonth - 1);

System.out.println("Maximum number of days is: " + cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Comment: Thank you, I used this to also include a year as well, so leap years are correct for February. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> At the moment it outputs the max number of days for month we're currently in (March).

`Calendar.getInstance()` returns current time, thus current month. You should:

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, myMonth - 1);
 int actualMax = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Calendar object and set its month to the value the user has enter -1 (as month start with 0 in Calendar.)

Then get the ActualMaximum of that Calendar

Answer (score 1):

The answer is more like a combination of the two previous answers.

For example, to get the maximum days of February, than *myMonth* would be equal to 2

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int myMonth = 2;
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, myMonth - 1);
    System.out.println(c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}
```

Comment: Whoops, I think my answer came in as a duplicate to @ozgd's. Either one will give you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Yoda time its even simpler:

```
DateTime last = new DateTime().
                withMonthOfYear(myMonth).
                dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue();
```

Comment: doesn't it still produce value for current month?

Comment: my hands, they ate a part of what I wanted to write - fixed now :)

Answer (score 1):

```
   import java.util.*;

   public class LastDay {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);       
      GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();

      int myMonth;

      System.out.println("Enter the month number (1-12): ");
      myMonth = scanner.nextInt();

      Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();   
      calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, myMonth-1, Calendar.DATE);

      System.out.println("Maximum number of days is: " + calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));     
}
```

}